# If possible, what would be the conditions for a planet like Earth to have an emerald green sky in its twilight zone?

Tags: planets, atmosphere, solar-system, colors

Regardless, how can I get an idea of ​​how the color of starlight, or any other natural phenomenon, impacts the color of the sky at different times of day?

Comment: This question is likely a duplicate of either [What kind of atmospheric composition would make the sky look green and still be breathable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/225631) or [is there any way to make an earthlike planet (aside from the atmosphere) have a green sky at noon and a pink sky at dusk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/197009). However, you have not provided enough information to know if they are... or not. I get that the twilight reference probably disqualifies the second (though it's worth looking at), but you need to explain the rest of your atmo. ...

Comment: ... Please consider the responses carefully, the goal is to inform you, not just to get an answer to your question. If neither of those two questions solve your problem, please [edit] your post with both (a) an explanation of the details of your atmopshere and (b) a clear explanation for why the two questions don't solve your problem.